# Same query runs in SQL Server Management Studio and fails in Flyway Migration script

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, flyway, alter-table

I'm executing the following query :
`ALTER TABLE MYTABLE_01 ADD COL_03 VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT 'my column';`
In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I could execute the query with no problem and the column was created as expected. Whereas, my flyway script including this query failed with the following error message :

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V2_1__ALTER_TABLE.sql failed
---------------------------------------------
SQL State  : S0001
Error Code : 156
Message    : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.
Location   : .../mssql/V2_1__ALTER_TABLE.sql (C:\...\V2_1__ALTER_TABLE.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE MYTABLE_01 ADD COL_03 VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT 'my column';
```

Does anyone have any idea why do this error occur although the query is correct ?

Comment: I couldn't recreate this using flyway 4.1.1 targeting SQL 2014 with the jTDS driver. Are you using a different version/driver?

Comment: @EdHarper I use com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver as driver, SQL Server 2008 and Flyway 4.0. But I don't think it has something to do with the versions.